# VS Code snippet with multiple transforms

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am trying to make a snippet that will take clipboard contents (the text of a heading in a `markdown` document) and transform it into a link to that section. For example, if my clipboard contains: `Some Heading - 20191107` then I want the following to be output:

```
[Some Heading - 20191107](filename.md#some-heading---20191107)
```

Here is my snippet `VS Code` for `markdown` so far:

```
    "link to this section": {
        "prefix": "isection",
        "body": [
            "[${1:${CLIPBOARD}}](${TM_FILENAME}#${CLIPBOARD/ /-/g})"
        ],
        "description": "Insert link to section whose heading text is in the clipboard"
    }
```

This has the first transform, but what I cannot figure out is how to nest multiple transforms:

- Replace all space with a hyphen.
- Change all to lower case.
- Remove any characters matching `[^a-z0-9-]`

## Test Case

To clarify my test case for @Mark, in a `markdown` document in `VS Code`, I make a section heading such as:

```
# 20191107 - @#$%^& This is a section - 20191107
```

I then copy the text `20191107 - @#$%^& This is a section - 20191107` and run the snippet you fixed up for me. What it outputs is:

```
[20191107 - @#$%^& This is a section - 20191107](tips.tech.git.md#20191107----this-is-a-section---20191107)
```

Which is a valid link to the heading!

Comment: Ideally how would you like the output to look in your test case?  I used `Some Heading - 20191107` from your original question to design the regex but it looks like `# 20191107 - @#$%^& This is a section - 20191107` is really what you are starting with?

Comment: That was just an example so that I can test what it will do with headings that have non-alphanumeric characters in it. It works perfectly btw - exactly what I was trying to create myself. The most important part is the way it creates the link part - within the round brackets. If you don't mind giving a bit of explanation on the regex, that would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a snippet that I believe meets all requirements (I have simplified this from an earlier answer of mine).

```
"link to this section": {
  "prefix": "isection",
  "body": [

    "[${1:${CLIPBOARD}}](${TM_FILENAME}#${CLIPBOARD/([\\w-]+$)|([\\w-]+)|([-\\s]+)|([^\\w]+)/${1:/downcase}${2:/downcase}${2:+-}/gm})"

  ],
  "description": "Insert link to section whose heading text is in the clipboard"
}
```

I will explain this part:

`${CLIPBOARD/([\\w-]+$)|([\\w-]+)|([-\\s]+)|([^\\w]+)/${1:/downcase}${2:/downcase}${2:+-}/gm}`

The main idea here is to capture each group to be handled differently in its own group.  A regex alternation will just capture one group for each match.  See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/AKDFqT/1).

Then you can transform that group or ignore it without affecting any subsequent matches!

It is alternation of four capture groups:

1. `([\\w-]+$)`  note the `$` to indicate end of line, must be first capture group
2. `([\\w-]+)`  same as group 1, but not at end of line
3. `([-\\s]+)`  capture spaces and hyphens in a group
4. `([^\\w]+)`  capture any characters other than `A-Za-z0-9` in a group

*Capture group 1* gets the **last** set of characters, like `12345` or `asdasd`.

*Capture group 2* gets the same groups of characters as group 1 but not if they are at the end of the line.  This is important because a `-` will be added if there is a capture group 2, but not if there is a capture group 1 (so no hyphen is added to the end).

*Capture group 3* captures the spaces and hyphens.  It will be ignored in the output.

*Capture group 4* captures those non-`A-Za-z0-9` characters and will be ignored.

Here is the output of the transform: `${1:/downcase}${2:/downcase}${2:+-}`  notice there is no mention of groups 3 or 4 - they are being discarded.  But they must be matched otherwise they will pass through "un-transformed" and appear in the result - which we do not.

So lowercase groups 1 and 2, because of the alternation there will never be both in the same match.

`${2:+-}` **if** there is a group 2 add a `-` after it.  The very last match of the entire CLIPBOARD will be a group 1 so for this last match no hyphen will be appended.

Because of the `g` flag the regex runs a few times, each time capturing only one of the 4 groups.

---

Input: `Some Heading - 20191107`
Output: `[Some Heading - 20191107](fileName.ext#some-heading-20191107)`

Input: `20191107 - @#$%^& This is a section - 20191107`
Output: `[20191107 - @#$%^& This is a section - 20191107](test-bed-snippets.code-snippets#20191107-this-is-a-section-20191107)`

---

If you need more hyphens in the result, like:

`[Some Heading - 20191107](filename.md#some-heading---20191107)`

just take the hyphen out of the third capture group: `([\\s]+)` to result in:

`[20191107 - @#$%^& This is a section - 20191107](test-bed-snippets.code-snippets#20191107---this-is-a-section---20191107)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mark. In answer to your question the text may include any character at all. The rule for creating the anchor tag for a Markdown heading is: 1) replace all spaces with hyphen, 2) lower case everything, remove every non-alphanumeric character (or hyphen).

Comment: Wow, that works and make eyes cross just slightly when I try to read it. :D Would love an explanation. For a test with this text (from a markdown header): `20191107 - @#$%^& This is a section - 20191107` it generated this markdown : `[20191107 - @#$%^& This is a section - 20191107](notes.md#20191107----this-is-a-section---20191107)` which correctly linked to the heading in VS Code.

Comment: Not sure I quite follow your test case.  `20191107 - @#$%^& This is a section - 20191107` that whole thing is a test case?  And the transform works as you want on that test case?

Comment: Updated my question test to hopefully explain it!

Comment: It would be great if this answer could be adapted to better explain the generic part of the question: "write snippet with multiple transforms". At the moment, I have to decipher the regex myself. Hence this answer is just a working example from my perspective.

Comment: Robert and @RomainVincent I have finally gotten to explaining my answer (and simplified the transform) in the process.  Let me know if it works as you expect or don't understand something.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanations, that's very nice of you. I think I don't understand, why group 1 must be first? It would never be match otherwise maybe?

Comment: @Romain If `([\\w-]+$)` is not first then the last sequence of characters, like `20191107` in the OP's example, will be matched by `([\\w-]+)` We need them in different groups so we can use `${2:+-}` to only add the hyphen to groups that are **not** at the end.

Comment: @Romain If `([\\w-]+)` is at the beginning, it will match that last group up until the `$` and then `([\\w-]+$)` wouldn't match anything as all the preceding text before the `$` had already been matched.