# VS Code Snippets Multiple Transforms on a single variable

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

Was reading [VS Code snippet with multiple transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740859/vs-code-snippet-with-multiple-transforms) and I tried very hard, but was unable to parse how it's being done.

I have a requirement to use `${TM_FILEPATH}` and snip out everything preceding a certain point and replace all `\` with `/`.

For both paths of `/path/to/lib/file.c` and `C:\path\to\lib\file.c`, I need the results to be `/lib/file.c`

I have the first part done for my use case:

```
${TM_FILEPATH/.*lib//}
```

I can't seem to do the second, though. I've tried:

```
 ${TM_FILEPATH/\\/\//g}
```

And I need to do both. If someone answers this, could they also break it down so I can understand what's happening? I'd like to learn how to do these without having to keep asking.

Comment: the linked question does not do multiple transforms, it does multiple matches of the regex (`g`) and cleverly use the matched groups to apply different modifications on each matched group

Answer (score 0):

I updated the previous answer so it works much better now.

```
"PS3": {
  "prefix": "ps3",
  "body": [
    "${TM_FILEPATH/.+?(?=[\\/\\\\]lib)|([\\/\\\\])/${1:+/}/g}",
  ]
}
```

`.+?` match everything before what we want.  Must do this otherwise unmatched input will "pass through" and not be transformed or eliminated.

`(?=[\\/\\\\]lib)` a positive lookahead is not part of the match

`[\\/\\\\]` match either a `\` or an `/` Those characters must be double-escaped in a snippet.

`${1:+/}` in the replacement - if there was a \ or / matched, replace with a /

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips)

save this snippet in the `all.hsnips` file in the correct directory

```
snippet filePart "File Part"
`` rv = path.replace(new RegExp('.*?/path/to/'), '/'); ``
endsnippet
```

PS. Hypersnips does not work in `.txt` files